# Can't import PrimeVue InputOpt in CDN project

Tags: vue.js, input, components, cdn, primevue

Trying to import InputOpt using:

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/primevue/inputopt/inputopt.min.js"></script>
```

It shows a 404 status message on console. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: CDN links should just work in the browser.  If you can't open the link, then the URL is wrong.  You have a typo.  it's not "OPT" it's "OTP", it stands for "one time password".  correct link: [https://unpkg.com/primevue/inputotp/inputotp.min.js](https://unpkg.com/primevue/inputotp/inputotp.min.js)

Comment: My bad, was just a typo, although stackoverflow doesn't allow me to mark your comment as the correct answer, just as useful comment, I don't know why.